# Commutator subgroup for the group of rotational symmetries of a Tetrahedron.

Tags: group-theory

Looking at the group of rotational symmetries of a Tetrahedron.

I can't seem to figure out what the commutator subgroup of this group would be.

Could someone possibly clarify it for me.

Comment: The group is non-abelian (OK?) and yet it permutes the three joins-of-opposite-edges in a cycle of order 3 (and no more)(OK?). The (normal) subgroup fixing each of the three joins-of-opposite-edges must  be what you want.

Comment: You may want to tell us how you describe that group (explicitly). A presentation? A set of permutations (if so, of what?) etc.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes perfect thank you. I get it now.